# AbstractMethodError when using Java Client to create ElasticSearch mapping

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm using Spring Data Elastic Search 2.1.12.RELEASE with elastic search 2.4.4.

I have the following code:

```
elasticsearchTemplate.createIndex(indexName);
elasticsearchTemplate.addAlias(alias);
elasticsearchTemplate.putMapping(MyElasticEntity.class);  //FAILS HERE!
```

And my entity is:

```
@Document(indexName = "psp", type = "payouts")
public class MyElasticEntity {

    @Id
    String id;

    UUID payoutId;

    // more fields of type UUID, enum, String, Instant and Long. Nothing unusual.

    @Version
    Long version;
}
```

My code fails in the `putMapping` above with:

> Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: null    at
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.createAndRegisterProperty(AbstractMappingContext.java:552)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.doWith(AbstractMappingContext.java:530)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:729)
>   ~[spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:398)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:229)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:172)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:85)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate.getPersistentEntityFor(ElasticsearchTemplate.java:1094)
>   ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-2.1.12.RELEASE.jar:na]    at
>   org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate.putMapping(ElasticsearchTemplate.java:183)
>   ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-2.1.12.RELEASE.jar:na]    at
>   psp.elasticsearch.ESReindexingResource.reindexPayouts(ESReindexingResource.java:60)
>   ~[classes/:na]    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method) ~[na:1.8.0_172]   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_172]   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_172]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_172]   at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:877)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:783)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]  ... 86 common frames
>   omitted

It seems the implementation used is of type `org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.mapping.SimpleElasticsearchMappingContext` which does define a `createPersistentProperty()` implementation.

Googling around I found suggestions that I have incompatible versions of libraries. I suspect that's the cause, but can't seem to find the issue.

Someone suggested to include `spring-data-commons` on my pom file but that didn't work (probably because I added the wrong version - it was already there anyway, via transitive dependencies).

If I create the mapping with a curl command and then just add documents, it works, so it definitely something wrong either in my java code (which is as simple as what I've shared) or the dependencies.

Any ideas how do fix or better debug this?